# MySQL 5.7.28 - cannot disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - non-aggregated columns

Tags: mysql

I have removed `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from sql_mode. The following query returns no modes enabled.

`SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`

But still when using **group by**, I am receiving non-aggregated columns

> (this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by) error.

Comment: 1) Look session variable - global setting of SQL mode has no effect in session, it only sets starting value which may be freely altered later; 2) Look its value immediately before the query which causes an error; 3) Try to remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` immediately before query execution using multi-query (guaranteeing it is altered in the same connection) by `SET @@sql_mode=REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '')` (do not set the mode to empty value!).

Comment: @Akina Thanks a lot. It was getting overridden before query execution. You were absolutely right.

Comment: I just don't believe in miracles.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**: Remove Globally ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY using query

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
mysql>SET @@sql_mode=REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '');
```

Refer: http://johnemb.blogspot.com.ng/2014/09/adding-or-removing-individual-sql-modes.html

**Option 2**: Set sql_mode to nothing...

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

**Option 3**: Remove Globally ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from phpmyadmin

1. Open phpmyadmin & select localhost
2. Click on menu Variables & scroll down for sql mode
3. Click on edit button to change the values & remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY & click on save.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this. Also, restarted mysql, sql mode has no `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. Still this problem exists.

Comment: @ Ronak I had tried all of your options. The comment by Akina solved it.

Comment: @VardhanM try ```sql
SET SESSION sql_mode='';
```